# How to change the color of floating action button in xml file or programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I am novice for the android world. Just for improving my skills, I am learning android. So I am creating a social app there I have used floating action button, on which if user clicks it increases the number of likes.

**By default, floating button is taking accent color but I want to use different color.** I tried a lot but not getting any solution. Yes, there are so many libraries available that I can use to achieve my goal, but I do not want to use any external library. I believe to use core methods of android.

**Is it like, there is no solution except using external libraries?** I tried this one, but xml file is throwing error when I am using **app** tag.

```
If you wish to change the color

    in XML with attribute app:backgroundTint
    in code with .setBackgroundTintList
```

I am using this library:

> com.android.support:design:23.1.1

Please comment on the same. I know for Android guru's this is not big deal. I know this question has been already but I didn't get solution for my problem. That's why I am opening this question again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the documentation, by default it takes the color set in styles.xml attribute colorAccent.

> The background color of this view defaults to the your theme's colorAccent. If you wish to change this at runtime then you can do so via setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList).

If you wish to change the color

In XML with attribute app:backgroundTint

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    ...
    app:backgroundTint="@color/orange"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:elevation="6dp"
    app:fabSize="normal" />
```

in code use `setBackgroundTintList`

Comment: Thanks Silvans. Is there any difference if I use the app namespace after the layout namespace. Or it works only if I add the namespace inside the floating action button.

Comment: It will work for both, if you use name space in your root layout or inside floating button. Please accept answer if it worked for you.

Comment: Tonight I will check and let you know.

Comment: Thanks Silvans. It's working fine.

Comment: Great, Thanks for accepting this answer.

Comment: Silvans, I am facing error while using setBackgroundTintList, error is: **Call required API level 21 current min is 15**. Could you please tell me how I can get rid of this error.